# Which of the following conditions imply that $G$ is abelian?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group of order $n.$ Which of the following conditions imply
that $G$ is abelian?
a. $n = 15.$
b. $n = 21.$
c. $n = 36.$

I can see $a$ is true (since a cyclic group of order $3\times 5$) and $b$ is false (by considering $D_{36}$). But I'm skeptical about my solution for $b$ since the answer says group of order $21$ is not necessarily abelian even though

> if I consider $H,K$ to be the sylow 3 and sylow 7 subgroup then $G\simeq H\times K.$ Since $H,K$ are abelian so is $G.$

I don't know where did I go wrong?

Comment: How do you get $G\simeq H\times K$?

Comment: For order $21$, consider a semidirect product using that $\rm{Aut}(C_7)$ has a subgroup of order $3$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Isn't there any other way? I don't know semidirect product.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis, I can't see why you claim (c) is abelian and even less why the reason you mention would so imply...

Comment: @DominicMichaelis no, that is not even close to being correct.

Comment: @Tobias we did prove it in introduction to algebra. If it is not close to being correct tell me a counterexample

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Group_of_Order_Prime_Squared_is_Abelian

Comment: @DominicMichaelis the first part is right (square of prime). As soon as you add more primes, it becomes wrong. You need more conditions on the primes than being distinct.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft and what would those be ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis, yes: every group of order the square of a prime is abelian, but that does not mean that a group whose order is the product of two squares of primes is: not even close as mentioned already! For example, there are 10 non-abelian groups of order 36...!

Comment: I think that by $\,\prod p_i^2\;$ and etc. you meant *direct product*, which is not what we're talking about here.

Comment: you please verify whether you really mean "b is false (by considering $D_36$)" in your question.. I guess you want to say "c is false by considering $D_36$".

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Yes the OP meant what you noted. "c" is not necessarily abelian.

Comment: btw, i mean $D_{36}$ and not $D_36$ :P

Comment: I have up voted this question as it made me to think i forgot my group theory for some time :P.. I guess it is very natural to come to the conclusion as posed in the OP.. I was very confused for half an hour where did it go wrong ??

Comment: Lesson: If you choose to say "by that argument, $S_3$ is abelian," your next sentence should not effectively argue that $S_3\times S_3$ is abelian. :-)

Comment: @DonAntonio oh yes sorry I was half asleep. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a concrete example of a non-abelian group of order $21$, let us first consider a broader class of groups, namely those of affine transformations of a finite field.

So let $F$ be a finite field of order $q$ and consider the set of maps $F\to F$ of the form $x\mapsto ax + b$ with $a\neq 0$. It is easy to check that this set forms a group under composition (since these maps are bijective), and this group has order $q(q-1)$.

If $G$ is a subgroup of the multiplicative group of $F$, then restricting to those maps with $a\in G$ gives a new group, with order $q|G|$.

For the specific example of order $21$, we can take the finite field of order $7$ (so $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$) and the subgroup to be $\{1,2,4\}$. You should then check that the resulting group is not abelian.

The above class of groups is a great way to construct examples of non-abelian groups of various orders.

Answer (score 0):

In a group of order $\;15=3\cdot 5\;$ , both Sylow subgroups *must* be normal (and thus unique) by direct application of Sylow theorems, and this means the group is a direct product of these two subgroups, each of which is abelian (even cyclic) and thus the whole group also is abelian (and cyclic, in fact) .

In the other two cases we can construct a non-abelian group of that order using semidirect products. but since you haven't yet covered this I won't go further.

Comment: Aren't $D_{36}$ work for c?

Comment: I don't understand: what does "work" mean here? What you wrote in your question meant "for what values of $\,n\;$ a group of that order *necessarily* is abelian?", and that's what I addressed in my answer: there is only one group of order $\;15\;$ up to isomorphism and it is the cyclic one, and thus abelian, one. In the other two cases there is at least one non-abelian group of that order.

Comment: I meant to say that I can see dihedral group of order $36$ is nonabelian. So a group of that order $36$ is not necessarily abelian whence $c$ can be removed from the consideration.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the (non-abelian) semidirect product of $C_7$ and $C_3$ as follows: We view $C_7$ as the additive integers $\text{mod}7$ and $C_3$ as the subgroup of $\Bbb Z_7^*$ of order $3$, this is the multiplicative group $\{1, 2, 4\}$. Then $G=\Bbb Z_7\times \{1, 2, 4\}$ and multiplication is defined by $$(a,b)*(c,d)=(ad+c,bd).$$ Check that the multiplication is associative, then the neutral element is $(0,1)$ and inverses are given by the rule $(a,b)^{-1}=(-ab^{-1},b^{-1})$.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder you already have an answer for some part of your Question :

> If I consider $H,K$ to be the sylow 3 and sylow 7 subgroup then $G\cong H\times K$. Since $H,K$ are abelian so is $G$.

i remember you posed similar question asking to verify a proof that "any group of order $85$ is cyclic".

to show $G\cong H\times K$ it is not enough to show $H\leq G$, $K\leq G$ and $|H\times K|=|G|$

you need to prove that $H\unlhd G$ and $K\unlhd G$

In general it is not true that any sylow-$3$-subgroup in a group of order $21$ is normal (you please check it).

So, what you say i.e., $G\cong H\times K$ is not true in general.

So, there may possibly exist a nonabelian group of order $21$.

I hope you are happy now at least that you came out from a wrong notion.

Now expecting the possibility of existence of non abelian group :

> I would suggest you to make a copy of (more generalized) group of order $21$ in a way similar to that you construct a dihedral group. (this is what comes to my mind if i want to construct non abelian group if i am sure there does exist a possible non abelian group. though i fail most of the times (:P) i feel one should not fear of getting defeated)

So, what we do in dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is take an element $r$ of order $n$ and an element $s$ of order $2$ and generate the group with an extra condition that $srs^{-1}=r^{-1}$.

With same motivation, as $21=3.7$ i take an element of order $7$ and an element of order $3$ and write very similar relation as that of  $srs^{-1}=r^{-1}$.

I know there exists an element of order $7$ (thanks to cauchy theorem and sylow(??)) say $a$ and an element of order $3$ (thanks to cauchy theorem and sylow(??)) say $b$.

we have $a,b\in G$ with $'a'$ generator of sylow $7$ subgroup and $'b'$ a generator of sylow $3$ subgroup.

As we know that any sylow $7$ subgroup is normal, $bab^{-1}\in \langle a\rangle$ (??)

So, $bab^{-1}$ has to be one of $1,a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5,a^6$

one see that $bab^{-1}\neq 1$ in which case $a=1$ and $bab^{-1}\neq a$ (in which case $ab=ba$ and so $G$ is abelian and we do not want that).

So the next option is $bab^{-1}=a^2$, I do not see any problem with this and i see that i have exactly $21$ elements (??) in $\{\big<a,b\big> : |a|=7, |b|=3 ,bab^{-1}=a^2\}$.

So, I have got a non abelian group of order $21$ with

> $G=\{\big<a,b\big> : |a|=7, |b|=3 ,bab^{-1}=a^2\}$

please try to check what would happen if $bab^{-1}=a^i$ for $3\leq i\leq 6$ (which i have not checked out)

P.S : I tried my best to use nothing more than cauchy/sylow theorem as you said you are not familiar with semi direct product. please let me know if you see any traces of that as i also want to write it down more elementarily.